# Is there a free sharepoint hosting site where I can try out Access 2013 asset tracking template?

Tags: excel, hosting

Is there a free sharepoint hosting site where I can try out Access 2013 asset tracking template? I just want to see how it works.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you can do it using SharePoint Online preview, please check this article - http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-access/archive/2012/07/30/get-started-with-access-2013.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I came across this website few days back on LinkedIn as they were providing free SharePoint 2013 site for learning purposes.

http://www.sharepointpower.com/Pages/Default.aspx

I created a site for myself and it worked, I could customize it and that, however I have been told its under construction when few mates I refereed but you can give it a go.